# Consider defining a bean of type in your configuration: MyBatis

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am new to the whole spring ecosystem. I've been following some tutorials and was able to create a spring boot application and performed crud operations. Then I started changing that project to standards of mybatis.

I have tried many answers to other similar questions but none are working so far.

Here is the problem statement:

```
//CustomerService.java

package com.crudapp.service;

import com.crudapp.entity.Customer;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public interface CustomerService {

    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers();
//I have other methods as well to delete, update and post.

}
```

The implementation class is implemented as:

```
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

    @Autowired
    private CustomerMapper customerMapper;

    @Override
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        List<Customer> list = customerMapper.getAllCustomers();
        return list;
    }
}
```

My Mapper class is like this:

```
@Mapper
public interface CustomerMapper {

    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers();
}
```

My Mapper.xml class is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN"  "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >
<mapper namespace="com.crudapp.mapper.CustomerMapper">
    <select id="getAllCustomers" resultType="customer">
        select * from customers
    </select>
</mapper>
```

and finally my Controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public class CustomerController {

    @Autowired
    CustomerService customerService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAllCustomers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        List<Customer> list = customerService.getAllCustomers();
        return list;
    }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

> Description:
>
> Field customerMapper in com.crudapp.service.impl.CustomerServiceImpl
> required a bean of type 'com.crudapp.mapper.CustomerMapper' that could
> not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type 'com.crudapp.mapper.CustomerMapper'
> in your configuration.

The error is straightforward without a doubt. I think the two @Autowired I have one in the controller the other in service implmentation might be the problem. But my understanding is that the bean will be auto-managed by the framework. So, how would I fix this?

**UPDATE:**
By adding `@MapperScan("com.crudapp.mapper")` the above error is no longer there but I'm getting this new error:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'customerRepo' defined in
> com.crudapp.repository.CustomerRepo defined in
> @EnableJpaRepositories declared on
> JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.EnableJpaRepositoriesConfiguration:
> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class
> com.crudapp.entity.Customer

My main class is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan("com.crudapp.mapper")
public class CrudappApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CrudappApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

In my application.properties file I have:

```
mybatis.config=classpath:mapper/mybatis_config.xml
mybatis.typeAliasesPackage=com.crudapp.entity
mybatis.mapperLocations=classpath*:**/mappers/*.xml
```

[image]

Comment: You can try `@Component` annotation over `CustomerMapper` interface

Comment: should I remove the @Mapper and replace it or should I add it on top of Mapper? I tried it both ways the error is the same.

Comment: Now the problem seems to be in `Customer` class. Please share the code

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have this in your properties file

mybatis.typeAliasesPackage=com.sivalabs.demo.domain
mybatis.mapperLocations=classpath*:**/mappers/*.xml

Ref : https://dzone.com/articles/spring-boot-working-with-mybatis

And MapperScan annotation

```
@SpringBootApplication
@MapperScan("com.sivalabs.demo.mappers")
public class SpringbootMyBatisDemoApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringbootMyBatisDemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added this and there are new errors. I've updated the question accordingly, please advise on what else I might be missing?

Comment: add @Service in your interface Customer Service as well.

Comment: @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages={"com.crudapp"})  - add this and try again

Comment: Adding the @SpringBootApplication... as well as adding @Service on service interface and implementation I'm still getting `Error creating bean with name 'customerController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'customerService';` :(

Comment: I have been following this tutorial: https://programmer.help/blogs/spring-boot-integrates-mybatis-and-completes-crud-operations.html

Comment: Try this @ComponentScan("com.project") for unsatisifed dependency Ref : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-unsatisfied-dependency

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237543/discussion-between-senthil-and-chaudhry-talha).